# How to make Firefox 22 to do not scale?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, dpi

After auto update to Mozilla Firefox version 22, icons are blured and fonts are scaled (so it looks big). It seems that it starts using the system DPI. How to revert this feature to keep Firefox raster icons unblured?  (To scale web pages I am already using NoSquint addon.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found this: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=12890981#p12890981:

First to change `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` to `1.0` in `about:config`. (Use [NoSquint addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/nosquint/) again to scale web pages.) And then apply the styles from the link to [userChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome.css) to get reasonable font size in Firefox chrome.